# How to set Toolbar at Right side of screen when screen moving from portrait mode to landscape mode?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I made a screen in portrait mode Something like this:

[image]

below three image inside toolbar
 But I want in landscape mode it look something like this:

[image]

But I couldn't manage to move the toolbar right Side of screen.

Below is my toolbar.xml file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbarmenucontainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_location"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_people"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

One more thing How can I make collapsible google map as shown in figure.on click of red band it expand from bottom to top and from top to bottom.Any help would be appreciated in advanced.

Comment: its not possible to change position of toolbar. until you hide toolbar & add view like toolbar at right side in your layout when screen in landscape

Comment: create another layout file 'same name as this file' and add it into 'layout-land' folder

Comment: thx for ur response.. can u explain me how can i add view in landscape mode..actually i'm new in android .so i didn't get it clearly.. plzzz

Comment: you don't need to do anything, when your phone is in landscape mode it will automatically pick the layout file from 'layout-land' folder. But make sure to use the same xml file name

Comment: @kishorepatel: its not working..toolbar still align at bottom of screen

Comment: Any other suggestions plz..

Comment: Actually i used this toolbar in Linealayout..

Comment: 1) Do not use Toolbar for this. Just put the items as ImageButtons directly inside the LinearLayout. Make another layout file in /res/layout-land/ and reposition the elements as you want them in landscape. Android should load the appropriate file when you rotate screen then.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use two layout xml files: one that is used when the screen is in portrait mode, and one that is used when the screen is in landscape mode.

- The portrait file has the bar on the top
- The landscape one has it on the side

**Option 1:** Then you can put them in the appropriate resource folders:

- `/layout-land` for the lansdcape one
- `/layout-port` for the portrait one
- With this option, your `Activity`'s `onCreate()` is called each time the orientation changes as the `Activity` is actually recreated.

**Option 2:** Alternatively, you can also detect and handle the orientation programmatically:

*Caveat*: this option shouldn't be preferred unless you have reasons not to use the Android built-in orientation handling system described in option 1. For example, if you need the `Activity` NOT to be re-created.

- in your `Manifest`, add a `configChange` detector to your `Activity`:

  ```
  <activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:configChanges="orientation" />
  ```
- in your `Activity`, catch the config change to use the proper layout XML file:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {        
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

      // set the Layout file to use using newConfig.orientation. For example:
      final boolean isLandscape = (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); 

      setContentView(isLandscape ? R.layout.toolbar_horizontal : R.layout.toolbar_vertical); 

      doAnyOtherNeededStuffAccordingToTheScreenOrientation(isLandscape);
  }
  ```
- With this option, your `Activity` is not re-created, so `onCreate()` is not called at orientation change. This is prevented by catching/handling the `configChanges` event.

Comment: Do NOT EVER take Option 2.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Well, it depends on what you need to do. I was led to use both options in the past and I'm still alive. Why "NOT EVER"?

Comment: @Shlublu Ok, don't use it unless you are perfectly aware of new responsibilities taken on yourself and potential pitfalls. Lets be honest, having the activity recreate itself instead of having to track everything by hand is a safer option for everyone.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Yes, you are absolutely right, option 2 is an alternative that should not be preferred unless you have a reason to. I modified my answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an alternate layout resource file with the name:
**res/layout-land**
There add your layout xml file with the toolbar at the right side. when the screen orientation changes the system will set your activity's content view from that directory.

Answer (score -1):

Add  **android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"**  for activity in AndroidManifest file

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Sample"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

you can change it in programmatically  like this

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```